# Display the date on a time series graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following script that displays graphs of a time series for a variable:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize']=30,50

dataset = read_csv('bnm_irrgation_well.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values

dataset.head(5)
```

```
date        208_63  420_36                                      
01/01/2008  376.26  407.0   
01/02/2008  NaN     NaN 
01/03/2008  NaN     406.1   
01/04/2008  NaN     NaN 
01/05/2008  375.3   NaN
```

```py
groups = [0,1]
i = 1

pyplot.figure()
for group in groups:
    pyplot.subplot(len(groups), 2, i)
    pyplot.plot(values[:, group])
    pyplot.title(dataset.columns[group], y=1, loc='center')
    i += 1
pyplot.show()
```

However, the X axis of the graph displays only the observation number, but I would rather it displays the date.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert dataframe to series by setting the date column as the index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: In which part of the script I should insert this line?

Comment: can you give me more details on how to modify this script?

Comment: Insert above dataset.head(5), also in the line I provided replace df with dataset as this is your dataframe.